# (Android) Call Fragment from other Package within the Project

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

So the scenario is

`com.example.fragment1.FragmentSample.class
com.example.fragment2.FragmentSample2.class
,,,
com.example.main.MainActivity.class`

so when my app start it will create fragmentsample as default and I like to call fragmentsample2 when I press the enter button in fragmentsample... but my code has always error how can i do this?? btw my mainactivity extend on activity... is this wrong like it should be FragmentAcitivity or is it ok?

Comment: FragmentActivity is for compatability with pre-Honeycomb, so if you don't need to support older stuff Activity it is ok. If you've read the Google Fragment guide then you should post some code.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, ADT is unhappy (doesn't recognize the R file) when Fragments don't belong to the same package as their Activity, so in your case you would need to move FragmentSample.java & FragmentSample2.java into com.example.main

If that doesn't solve your problem, you need to provide more detail on the error/s you're seeing.